# Managing Event's EventHandlers

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling, .net-1.1

I have a class that seems to be recursively adding an EventHandler to an event. I have looked at the code but there is no `AddHandler` on it and there's only one method with the `Handles` clause.

In the memory profiler it shows that the event handler is calling the event handler that is calling the event handler and so on for a rather large number of steps.

What could this be due to? What could be a good way to approach the situation in order to fix it?

P.S. I am new to this whole memory profiling thing so take it lightly on me ;).

Comment: Which language are you using? In C# the "+=" syntax is supported for adding event handlers, too.

Comment: @Lawrence: Given his mention of `AddEventHandler` (which I believe was intended to be `AddHandler`) and `Handles`, it could only be VB.NET

Comment: I'm using VB.NET... but what is to know why does the EventHandler keeps adding "recursively" in order to avoid it.

Comment: @Adam: you nailed it.. I fixed the typo :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you have an even whose handler is triggering the event again. The easiest way to tell this would be to set a breakpoint in the handler and see if it reenters the handler unexpectedly. If so, you can look at the stack trace and figure out what you're doing to trigger the event again.

If it's an event that might be affected by a pause (`Paint`, for example), you could write to the `Console` within the handler as well and print out `Environment.StackTrace` to get a snapshot without pausing execution.

Comment: I thought about this process and set a breakpoint in the signature of the method that contains the `Handles` clause but it never got there. For the action I'm debugging (that is madly consuming RAM) that method never gets executed.

Comment: @PedroC88: In that case, this has nothing to do with your event handler. You need to do the same thing within whatever function *is* getting called repeatedly. If this isn't clear, post a code sample.

Comment: I can't really post the code (although I know it's hard to help others this way) but I understand what you propose. I know which method is getting called repeatedly, but what should I look for therein?

Comment: @Pedro: If you know it's being called recursively, just take a look at the call stack after you've come back into it a couple of times. Whatever is between the call you're currently in and the previous call should help you figure out what's repeating the process.